# Data-structure to be store in array

Tags: arrays, data-structures, hierarchical-data

[image: Given this Data structure]
where GF : Grand father
      f1,f2,f3 : Father
      c1,c2,c3  : children

Q1. How to store this data structure in an array
Q2. Using above array , how to access all child elements ,ONLY?

Comment: @user1470033 can u post a more specific answer ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Father
    {
        char* Child1;
        char* Child2;
        char* Child3;
    };

struct Grandfather
{
    Father Father1 ;
    Father Father2;
    Father Father3;
};

const int MAXARRAYSIZE = 20;
Grandfather Grandfathers[MAXARRAYSIZE];


int main()
{   
    Grandfathers[0].Father1.Child1 = "The smart";
    Grandfathers[0].Father1.Child2 = "the brave";
    Grandfathers[0].Father1.Child3 = "the free";

    Grandfathers[0].Father2.Child1 = "The good";
    Grandfathers[0].Father2.Child2 = "the bad";
    Grandfathers[0].Father2.Child3 = "the ugly";

    Grandfathers[0].Father3.Child1 = "The boy";
    Grandfathers[0].Father3.Child2 = "the girl";
    Grandfathers[0].Father3.Child3 = "the other boy";

    //To print the children
    int CurrentArraySize = 1; //i can be changed with user input to accomodate more users for example, if there are 3 elements to the Grandfathers array i.e 3 different trees change CurrentArraySize to 3
    for(int i = 0; i < CurrentArraySize; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Children under Father1 are : "<<Grandfathers[i].Father1.Child1<<", "<<Grandfathers[i].Father1.Child2<<" and "<<Grandfathers[i].Father1.Child3<<endl;
        cout<<"Children under Father2 are : "<<Grandfathers[i].Father2.Child1<<", "<<Grandfathers[i].Father2.Child2<<" and "<<Grandfathers[i].Father2.Child3<<endl;
        cout<<"Children under Father3 are : "<<Grandfathers[i].Father3.Child1<<", "<<Grandfathers[i].Father3.Child2<<" and "<<Grandfathers[i].Father3.Child3<<endl;

    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: ok , i got the first part , how do i access each child node in the above data structure

Comment: @user1537158, Just added the code that access the "child" element

Comment: hmm @user1470033 , what iam trying to ask is , how can i write a code , to access all , only child nodes of the above tree

Comment: @user1537158 i don't think i'm understanding your question. Do you want to make Grandfathers[0].Father1 inaccessable But let Grandfathers[0].Father1.Child1 accessable?

Comment: hmm @user1470033 , no buddy nothing of that sort, i just want print all the child nodes of the above tree